# I would like to create an Excel Spreadsheet where every sheet is a list. Any advice on how I can do this. Do I need to make a list of lists?

Tags: c#

I have this code I am currently using:

```
CreateExcelFile.CreateExcelDocument(Start.ToList(), fileFolder + @"ExcelFiles/Start.xlsx");
CreateExcelFile.CreateExcelDocument(DateCPU1.ToList(), fileFolder + @"ExcelFiles/DateCPU1.xlsx");
CreateExcelFile.CreateExcelDocument(Start2.ToList(), fileFolder + @"ExcelFiles/Start2.xlsx");
```

The signature for the CreateExcelDocument is this:

```
public static void CreateExcelDocument<T>(List<T> list, string filepath)
```

Can someone tell me how I could call CreateExcelDocument with a List of Lists so I could output all of the my list information to the one Excel document instead of three.

For reference I'll include a copy of the code used to create the Excel below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Reflection;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet;

namespace Data1
{
    public class CreateExcelFile
    {
        public static void CreateExcelDocument<T>(List<T> list, string filepath)
        {
            try
            {
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                ds.Tables.Add(ListToDataTable(list));
                CreateExcelDocument(ds, filepath);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Trace.WriteLine("Failed, exception thrown: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }

        public static DataTable ListToDataTable<T>(List<T> list)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            foreach (PropertyInfo info in typeof(T).GetProperties())
            {
                dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(info.Name, GetNullableType(info.PropertyType)));
            }
            foreach (T t in list)
            {
                DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
                foreach (PropertyInfo info in typeof(T).GetProperties())
                {
                    if (!IsNullableType(info.PropertyType))
                        row[info.Name] = info.GetValue(t, null);
                    else
                        row[info.Name] = (info.GetValue(t, null) ?? DBNull.Value);
                }
                dt.Rows.Add(row);
            }
            return dt;
        }
        private static Type GetNullableType(Type t)
        {
            Type returnType = t;
            if (t.IsGenericType && t.GetGenericTypeDefinition().Equals(typeof(Nullable<>)))
            {
                returnType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(t);
            }
            return returnType;
        }
        private static bool IsNullableType(Type type)
        {
            return (type == typeof(string) ||
                    type.IsArray ||
                    (type.IsGenericType &&
                     type.GetGenericTypeDefinition().Equals(typeof(Nullable<>))));
        }

        public static bool CreateExcelDocument(DataTable dt, string xlsxFilePath)
        {
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            ds.Tables.Add(dt);
            bool result = CreateExcelDocument(ds, xlsxFilePath);
            ds.Tables.Remove(dt);
            return result;
        }

        public static bool CreateExcelDocument(DataSet ds, string excelFilename)
        {
            try
            {
                using (SpreadsheetDocument document = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(excelFilename, SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook))
                {
                    WriteExcelFile(ds, document);
                }
                Trace.WriteLine("Successfully created: " + excelFilename);
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Trace.WriteLine("Failed, exception thrown: " + ex.Message);
                return false;
            }
        }

        private static void WriteExcelFile(DataSet ds, SpreadsheetDocument spreadsheet)
        {
            spreadsheet.AddWorkbookPart();
            spreadsheet.WorkbookPart.Workbook = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Workbook();
            spreadsheet.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Append(new BookViews(new WorkbookView()));
            WorkbookStylesPart workbookStylesPart = spreadsheet.WorkbookPart.AddNewPart<WorkbookStylesPart>("rIdStyles");
            Stylesheet stylesheet = new Stylesheet();
            workbookStylesPart.Stylesheet = stylesheet;
            uint worksheetNumber = 1;
            foreach (DataTable dt in ds.Tables)
            {
                string workSheetID = "rId" + worksheetNumber.ToString();
                string worksheetName = dt.TableName;
                WorksheetPart newWorksheetPart = spreadsheet.WorkbookPart.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();
                newWorksheetPart.Worksheet = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Worksheet();
                newWorksheetPart.Worksheet.AppendChild(new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.SheetData());
                WriteDataTableToExcelWorksheet(dt, newWorksheetPart);
                newWorksheetPart.Worksheet.Save();
                if (worksheetNumber == 1)
                    spreadsheet.WorkbookPart.Workbook.AppendChild(new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Sheets());

                spreadsheet.WorkbookPart.Workbook.GetFirstChild<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Sheets>().AppendChild(new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Sheet()
                {
                    Id = spreadsheet.WorkbookPart.GetIdOfPart(newWorksheetPart),
                    SheetId = (uint)worksheetNumber,
                    Name = dt.TableName
                });

                worksheetNumber++;
            }

            spreadsheet.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Save();
        }


        private static void WriteDataTableToExcelWorksheet(DataTable dt, WorksheetPart worksheetPart)
        {
            var worksheet = worksheetPart.Worksheet;
            var sheetData = worksheet.GetFirstChild<SheetData>();
            string cellValue = "";
            int numberOfColumns = dt.Columns.Count;
            bool[] IsNumericColumn = new bool[numberOfColumns];

            string[] excelColumnNames = new string[numberOfColumns];
            for (int n = 0; n < numberOfColumns; n++)
                excelColumnNames[n] = GetExcelColumnName(n);
            uint rowIndex = 1;

            var headerRow = new Row { RowIndex = rowIndex };  // add a row at the top of spreadsheet
            sheetData.Append(headerRow);

            for (int colInx = 0; colInx < numberOfColumns; colInx++)
            {
                DataColumn col = dt.Columns[colInx];
                AppendTextCell(excelColumnNames[colInx] + "1", col.ColumnName, headerRow);
                IsNumericColumn[colInx] = (col.DataType.FullName == "System.Decimal") || (col.DataType.FullName == "System.Int32");
            }
            double cellNumericValue = 0;
            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                ++rowIndex;
                var newExcelRow = new Row { RowIndex = rowIndex };  // add a row at the top of spreadsheet
                sheetData.Append(newExcelRow);

                for (int colInx = 0; colInx < numberOfColumns; colInx++)
                {
                    cellValue = dr.ItemArray[colInx].ToString();
                    if (IsNumericColumn[colInx])
                    {
                        cellNumericValue = 0;
                        if (double.TryParse(cellValue, out cellNumericValue))
                        {
                            cellValue = cellNumericValue.ToString();
                            AppendNumericCell(excelColumnNames[colInx] + rowIndex.ToString(), cellValue, newExcelRow);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        AppendTextCell(excelColumnNames[colInx] + rowIndex.ToString(), cellValue, newExcelRow);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private static void AppendTextCell(string cellReference, string cellStringValue, Row excelRow)
        {
            Cell cell = new Cell() { CellReference = cellReference, DataType = CellValues.String };
            CellValue cellValue = new CellValue();
            cellValue.Text = cellStringValue;
            cell.Append(cellValue);
            excelRow.Append(cell);
        }

        private static void AppendNumericCell(string cellReference, string cellStringValue, Row excelRow)
        {
            Cell cell = new Cell() { CellReference = cellReference };
            CellValue cellValue = new CellValue();
            cellValue.Text = cellStringValue;
            cell.Append(cellValue);
            excelRow.Append(cell);
        }

        private static string GetExcelColumnName(int columnIndex)
        {
            if (columnIndex < 26)
                return ((char)('A' + columnIndex)).ToString();

            char firstChar = (char)('A' + (columnIndex / 26) - 1);
            char secondChar = (char)('A' + (columnIndex % 26));

            return string.Format("{0}{1}", firstChar, secondChar);
        }
    }
}
```

2m

Comment: You also have `CreateExcelDocument(DataSet ds, string excelFilename)` which makes a workbook with one sheet per table in the dataset, and the method you're calling just builds a dataset with one datatable to pass to this. For many lists you just need to make many datatables, one per list, put them all in the same dataset and then call the dataset CreateExcelDocument - you already have code that does most of this so it should be easy to adapt. Or you could modify this code to work with lists and not datatables.

Comment: I see this method: ListToDataTable<T>(List<T> list) and I think the code is already doing that.

Comment: Yes, you just need to write code to make many datatables and add them all to the same DataSet then call the method with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current code will already do what you want. The CreateExcelDocument overload you're calling

- calls ListToDataTable<> to convert your List<> to a DataTable
- creates a DataSet that contains your single DataTable
- calls the CreateExcelDocument overload that accepts a DataSet and generates a single workbook with a separate sheet per DataTable.

So instead you just need to construct a DataSet and add three DataTables to it that you can generate from your List<>s:

```
var ds = new DataSet();
ds.Tables.Add(CreateExcelFile.ListToDataTable(Start.ToList()));
ds.Tables.Add(CreateExcelFile.ListToDataTable(DateCPU.ToList()));
ds.Tables.Add(CreateExcelFile.ListToDataTable(Start2.ToList()));
CreateExcelFile.CreateExcelDocument(ds, fileFolder + @"ExcelFiles/StartAndCPU.xlsx");
```